# Cooler mash tun: prevent leaks from faucet

Tags: equipment, mash-tun

I've add some mishaps with my standard Coleman-based mash tun, and I'm now left with a hole where the faucet was (some wort went *inside* the insulation, but I'd like to believe it won't impact temperature conservation).  I'm using a braid as filter.  I'm not a very bright handyman, hence:

**Question:** How can I put a faucet back in such a way that there is no chance wort can leak into the insulation?  How can I ensure that even when the braid is moved a bit when stirring the mash, no space will be created allowing wort to leak? *I don't have the original plastic piece that fitted the hole.*

My previous solution included some O-rings that got smashed by being on parts that were screwed too tight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my method.  Take a look at www.dennybrew.com.  I've used it for 17 years and 475 batches and it works perfectly.  You use a minikeg bung and a nylon valve.  I've found it much easier to build and more effective to use than a bulkhead.

[image: interior]

[image: exterior]

Comment: In the spirit of SE, would you mind including a little bit more information in your answer, pertaining to my specific problem?  Thanks!

Comment: I have to agree with @Michaël, isn't the whole point of the SE model to gather the best answers and information *here*, rather than simply referring people to your website?

Comment: Thanks.  Just trying to be succinct, since all the info is there.

Comment: I went with this option, with foodgrade silicone everywhere.  It works like a charm, and I did not even have to put a spigot (the tubing pressed in half blocks the liquid).  Not caring for hot side aeration, this gives a very minimalistic and super efficient system.  If I had to do it again, I'd do that and use one of those very large mesh bags for filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You want too look into the design of of a ["weldless bulkhead"](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/weldless-kettle-bulkhead.html). [The instruction/installation guide (PDF)](http://www.northernbrewer.com/documentation/FF-Weldless-Bulkheads.pdf) has a great breakaway view of the approach: using nipples, couplers, washers, orings and a locknut to compress the orings against the cooler walls to create a watertight seal. The trick is to get all the pieces appropriately sized, and to use a locknut that has a groove for the outer oring, such that it's evenly compressed rather than being squished. From outside to inside:

```
[locknut] [oring] [cooler wall/threaded nipple] [oring] [washer] [threaded coupler]
```

It sounds like you do have an oring involved, so perhaps the nut was over-tightened, pinching or squishing the oring, rather than compressing it?  Hard to say.